# Referencing FamFamFam plugin images from Grails app

Tags: css, grails, icons

I am developing a new application on Grails 2.2.4

I have included the FamFamFam plugin since it includes a lot of nice icons.

The FamFamFam plugin documentation instructs about referencing FamFamFam icons from CSS but it doesn't seem to be working.

The plugin was last updated in 2010, possibly, it doesn't even work with Grails 2.x.

My CSS button style definition:

```
.execute-search {
  background-image: url('${fam.icon(name: 'world')}');
  background-position: 0.7em center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: 25px;
}
```

Also, I am not sure if one can place Grails expressions in the CSS files like this. The FamFamFam plugin doesn't say anything about needing extra settings or configuration.

Inspecting the element with Firebug, I see the Groovy expression in the stylesheet unprocessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use fam.icon in a CSS file since it's not processed like a GSP - it's just served directly as a text file. That code has to be in a GSP.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to reference the Fam icons in any way from a CSS file? I wouldn't like to directly reference the icons in my GSP/taglib since that way, it would loose the possibility of easy re-styling later.

Comment: You can put the CSS in a template or a taglib and reuse it that way. You might also look at sass and less.